# disable hover and active pseudo class for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, hover

Is it possible to disable the hover and active pseudo classes for mobile devices only?

I've found this

```
html.touch {
  /* Touch is enabled */
}

html.no-touch {
  /* Touch is disabled */
}
```

Which seems pretty neat. But I can't get it to work.

The code is below, and you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5qb2J/

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#button{background:url("http://www.webstuffshare.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/button3.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;display:block;width:201px;height:67px;}
#button:hover{background-position:0px -67px;}
#button:active{background-position:0px -134px;}
#button span{position:absolute;top:-99999999em;}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
<a id="button" href="#"><span>this is foo</span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### edit

I'm using this now

```
<?php // detect mobile
$Mobile = FALSE;
if
(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "android") ||
strstr(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "webos") ||
strstr(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "iphone") ||
strstr(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "ipod") ||
strstr(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "ipad") ||
strstr(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "zune"))
{
$Mobile = TRUE;
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
If ($Mobile == FALSE)
{
echo <<<escapethis
some html here
escapethis;
}
?>
```

the lines that use the word escapethis can not begin with a space

Comment: There are better sites to testcase HTML/CSS: http://jsfiddle.net and http://dabblet.com are prominent. Never use w3schools.

Comment: There's **nothing** wrong with w3schools, and it's actually fairly helpful for beginners learning HTML, CSS, JavaScript/jQuery, PHP, etc. but the editor, yeah don't use that for code sharing, [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a lot better :) I edited your question with a link to a jsfiddle.

Comment: There **are** some things _"wrong"_ with w3schools .. http://www.w3fools.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `html.touch` and `html.no-touch` are being used with a feature detection library like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which will do all sorts of feature testing and add classes to the `html` element based on the results of those tests.

In that case, you would want to do something like this:

```
html.no-touch #ElementThatShouldHaveNoHoverEventOnTouchDevices:hover{
    //do your stuff
}

<div id="ElementThatShouldHaveNoHoverEventOnTouchDevices">
    hello
</div>
```

Comment: I've found another solution while searching for modernizr (see edited post). I'll mark this as answered anyway.